# How to use a returned array in a success function?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ajax

When I try to use the returned array data on view page, it prints undefined not array value. Please help me.

My controller is:

```
function test(){
    $pro_id = $this->input->post('id',TRUE);
    //echo $pro_id;
    $cat_id = $this->input->post('cat',TRUE);

    $date1 = $this->input->post('dt',TRUE);
    $firstdate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date1));

    $lastdate = strtotime(date("Y-m-d", strtotime($firstdate)) . " +6 day");
    //echo $cat_id;
    $data = array();
    $this->load->model('inserttimemodel');
    $whr = $this->inserttimemodel->gettime($pro_id,$cat_id,$firstdate,$lastdate);
    $data['whr'] = $whr;  
    //print_r($data);  //working properly 
    echo json_encode($data);
    exit();                
}
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#cat").change(function(){
        var catid = $(this).val();
        var id = $('#project option:selected').val();
        var dt = $('#period option:selected').val();
        $.ajax({
            url:"<?php echo base_url();?>/timesheet/test",
            data:{cat:catid,id:id,dt:dt},
            type:"POST",
            dataType: "json",
            success:function(data){
                document.getElementById("res").innerHTML = data[0];  
                document.getElementById("res1").innerHTML = data[1];  
            }
        });
    });   
});
```

Comment: Try diagnosing your code by adding a console.log(data) statement inside your success callback and then checking your browser's console.

Comment: Looking at your PHP, your data should reside inside data.whr .

Comment: Array ( [whr] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [whr] => 1 ) [1] => Array ( [whr] => 2 ) [2] => Array ( [whr] => 3.3 ) [3] => Array ( [whr] => 6 ) [4] => Array ( [whr] => 5 ) [5] => Array ( [whr] => 8 ) [6] => Array ( [whr] => 5:30 ) ) )

Answer (score -2):

You need to decode "data" before using "JSON.parse" in Javascript.

Comment: Actually, jQuery parses json automatically when providing dataType: 'json' .